# Is it possible to convert MySQL to AWS(Amazon web services) later?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I'm creating the web application using(PHP) CodeIgniter framework with MySQL database. Later I want to replace MySQL to AWS(Amazon web services).

Is it possible? What are the challenges to face here?
I need your inputs folks!!!

If possible, Guide me with some examples.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use MySQL on AWS

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about Amazon RDS. It is pretty simple to migrate.

Step 1: Backup from MySQL

Step 2: Export to your Amazon RDS instance, you can use MySQL Workbench for this

Step 3: Configure your CodeIgniter database.php file to use the Amazon RDS.

You also ahve steps to create the database and all on AWS RDS, but thats all pretty self explained.